# Xamarin.forms pass in a variable to a tap gesture when triggered using behind code

Tags: xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a for loop which would loop out each view cell individual in xaml.cs. I added a tap gesture to the label but i need to differentiate the different label clicked by passing in the FilterName.

Below is my code for looping out the cells in the TableView

```
for (int m = 0; m < filterList.Count; m++) {
                ViewCell vc = new ViewCell {
                    View = new StackLayout {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                        Children = {
                            new Label () {
                                Text = "   " + filterList[m].filterName,
                                YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                                GestureRecognizers = {
                                    new TapGestureRecognizer() {
                                        Command = new Command(TapL_Tapped),
                                        CommandParameter = filterList[m].filterName
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Image () {
                                Source = FileImageSource.FromFile("check_mark.jpg"),
                                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                tableView.Root [0].Add (vc);
```

How do I pass the filterList[m].filterName to the TapL_Tapped to use it as a string? I tried with the command parameter but i am not sure what it exactly does. I tried to google how to pass in a variable using this method but to no avail, hope someone can guide me? Thank you:)

Below is the tap gesture method:

```
 void TapL_Tapped() {
 //to do events here
 //can i pass in the string here?
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a Command the Execute function normally accepts an object parameter.

doing

```
void TapL_Tapped(object parameter)
```

should work but I don't have a quick project to test on at the moment. The CommandParameter should be passed through.

Looking at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/03/20/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake.aspx will show you how commands work.

Frameworks such as MVVMLight use classes called RelayCommand which just implements ICommand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution, but can resolve.

Below of "tableView.Root [0].Add (vc);", you can put this lines:

```
tableView.Root [0].Last().GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() {
                                          Command = new Command(TapL_Tapped),
                                          CommandParameter =   filterList[m].filterName
});
```

And don't forget of to remove the "new TapGestureRecognizer" that already exists.

I hope I've helped.
Hugs!